# Not able to take secure LDAP connection using perl NET::LDAPS

Tags: ssl, ldap

I trying to take a secure connection of AD server ( w2k12 ) using perl Net::LDAPs.

Steps:

```perl
$ldaps = Net::LDAPS->new('AD.server.ip', port => '636', verify => 'none', capath => 'W2K12AD-0-CA');
$binddn = "Administrator\@NAS.net";
$mesg = $ldaps->bind (dn=>$binddn, password=>'xxxx' );
```

Giving me error as:

> `errorMessage' => 'I/O Error An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

Any help would be great.

Comment: what does openssl s_client -connect AD.server.ip:636 tell you, are ssl correctly up and running?

Comment: My AD server is a windows machine. When I try to run command " openssl s_client -connect AD.server.ip:636" ..from another unix box, it timed out.  PS:  I am able to ping from same box.

Comment: socket: Connection timed out
connect:errno=110

Comment: Your AD is not set up for ssl, see http://gregtechnobabble.blogspot.dk/2012/11/enabling-ldap-ssl-in-windows-2012-part-1.html or some other site explaning how to enable  ldaps for AD

Comment: Ahh.. i have enabled it using same link and verified it with ldp.exe but issue is still the same.

Comment: May be some issues with CApath or cacert ..No idea anyhelp on it

Comment: firewall in server 2012? Otherwise i'm out of ideas. I do not think it is a perl issue, just now I tested Net::LDAPS against a 2008 AD with success

Comment: My firewall is also off but anyways, Can you paste the code here....i can also test it in win2k8......if there are any additional certificate ( or anything that i need to take care of ) please mention.  Thanks for help

Comment: `#/usr/bin/perl
use Net::LDAPS;
my $ldaps = Net::LDAPS->new('hostname', port => '636', verify => 'require', capath => '/etc/ssl') or die $!;
$binddn = "Administrator\@nas.net"; 
$mesg = $ldaps->bind (dn=>$binddn, password=>'password' );
print $mesg->error_desc;` Try to use verify=>'require' and see the $! message.